# DynamoDB - How to upsert nested objects with updateItem

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb, upsert, dynamodb-queries, nested-object

Hi I am newbie to dynamoDB. Below is the schema of the dynamo table

```
{
   "user_id":1, // partition key
   "dob":"1991-09-12", // sort key 
   "movies_watched":{
      "1":{
         "movie_name":"twilight",
         "movie_released_year":"1990",
         "movie_genre":"action"
      },
      "2":{
         "movie_name":"harry potter",
         "movie_released_year":"1996",
         "movie_genre":"action"
      },
      "3":{
         "movie_name":"lalaland",
         "movie_released_year":"1998",
         "movie_genre":"action"
      },
      "4":{
         "movie_name":"serendipity",
         "movie_released_year":"1999",
         "movie_genre":"action"
      }
   }
..... 6 more attributes

}
```

I want to insert a new item if the item(that user id with dob) did not exist, otherwise add the movies to existing `movies_watched` map by checking if the movie is not already available the `movies_watched` map .

Currently, I am trying to use `update(params)` method.

Below is my approach:

```
function getInsertQuery (item) {
  const exp = {
    UpdateExpression: 'set',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {},
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {}
  }
  Object.entries(item).forEach(([key, item]) => {
    if (key !== 'user_id' && key !== 'dob' && key !== 'movies_watched') {
      exp.UpdateExpression += ` #${key} = :${key},`
      exp.ExpressionAttributeNames[`#${key}`] = key
      exp.ExpressionAttributeValues[`:${key}`] = item
    }
  })

  let i = 0
  Object.entries(item. movies_watched).forEach(([key, item]) => {
    exp.UpdateExpression += ` movies_watched.#uniqueID${i} = :uniqueID${i},`
    exp.ExpressionAttributeNames[`#uniqueID${i}`] = key
    exp.ExpressionAttributeValues[`:uniqueID${i}`] = item
    i++
  })
  exp.UpdateExpression = exp.UpdateExpression.slice(0, -1)
  return exp
}
```

The above method just creates update expression with expression names and values for all top level attributes as well as nested attributes (with document path).

It works well if the item is already available by updating `movies_watched` map. But throws exception if the item is not available and while inserting. Below is exception:

```
The document path provided in the update expression is invalid for update
```

However, I am still not sure how to check for duplicate movies in movies_watched map

Could someone guide me in right direction, any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this, given your model, without reading an item from DDB before an update (at that point the process is trivial). If you don't want to impose this additional read capacity on your table for update, then you would need to re-design your data model:

1. You can change movies_watched to be a Set and hold references to movies. Caveat is that Set can contain only Numbers or Strings, thus you would have movie id or name or keep the data but as JSON Strings in your Set and then parse it back into JSON on read. With SET you can perform ADD operation on the movies_watched attribute. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.ADD
2. You can go with single table design approach and have these movies watched as separate items with (PK:userId and SK:movie_id). To get a user you would perform a query and specify only PK=userId -> you will get a collection where one item is your user record and others are movies_watched. If you are new to DynamoDB and are learning the ropes, then I would suggest go with this approach. https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/dynamodb-single-table/